# When dynamically creating HTML elements with jQuery, how to include values conditionally in the JSON?

Tags: jquery, xml, json, checkbox

I'm creating a checkbox for every item in an XML file. The text of each file is `"TRUE"` or `"FALSE"`, and I want to create a checked checkbox for every `"TRUE"` and an unchecked checkbox for every `"FALSE"`. Right now my code is duplicated inside an if and an else because I can't think of a way to conditionally include the checked parameter in that JSON. Does anybody know a more DRY way to accomplish the same thing?

```
d = $(this)
if (d.text() === 'TRUE') {
    $('<input>', {
    className: 'checkbox',
    type: 'checkbox',
    id: d.attr('id'),
    name: d.attr('name'),
    checked: 'checked'
    }).appendTo(td);
}
else {
    $('<input>', {
    className: 'checkbox',
    type: 'checkbox',
    id: d.attr('id'),
    name: d.attr('name')
    }).appendTo(td);
}
```

Comment: Try use .serialize(), if it suits your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do it like this:

```
var d = $(this);
var options = {
        className: 'checkbox',
        type: 'checkbox',
        id: d.attr('id'),
        name: d.attr('name')
    };
options.checked = d.text() === 'TRUE' ? 'checked' : '';
/* --or if you think this is more readable
 *if (d.text() === 'TRUE') {
 *  options.checked = 'checked';
 *}
*/
$('<input>', options).appendTo(td);
```

There's no "rule" that states attribute maps can't be built ahead of time. :)

Comment: Thank you -- this was the key. The ternary doesn't work because if the checked attribute is present at all it will return checked. The if statement works and is DRY.

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = $(this),
    $input = $('<input>', {
        className: 'checkbox',
        type: 'checkbox',
        id: d.attr('id'),
        name: d.attr('name')
    }).appendTo(td);

if(d.text() === 'TRUE') $input.prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: That does not work. If the checked attribute is present at all it will return checked.

Comment: @MichaelHopkins Updated answer, with your suggestion